# Ruby On Rails - Access model from a different file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

I have a model in my rails application which is

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
..
end
```

I would like to access this model from a different ruby file for certain manipulations. This is to populate my db. Can somebody please tell me how to go about it?

I am new to ruby on rails and hence a trivial question. I tried including the model by using require or require relative but I get a LoadError

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a rake task to populate/manipulate your database then you can solve this problem by making the task depend on the rails environment, this will set up everything you need to access the db:

```
task :my_task => :environment do
#do whatever with your models here
end
```

Comment: Hi http://stackoverflow.com/users/1248820/tomdarkness , How do I set up rake tasks, I mean where does the file go in the framework? Can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: Hi Tomdarkness, I googled for basics of rake and went through rails casts and it worked like a breeze!

Comment: Thanks a ton for making my Friday a day! :)
PS: Stackoverflow rocks!! Awesome that I got such quick replies on Fridays as well!